# Moving windows between separate X screens

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xinerama, twinview

Is it possible to move a window that was opened on screen "A" (not workspace, but separate X screen) to screen "B" (with or without additional tools which aren't provided by Ubuntu)?

I have an nVidia card with proper drivers installed. I've tried using Xinerama / Twinview, but if one of these option are enabled (in /etc/xorg.conf) flash videos in Chromium (like on YouTube or Vimeo) doesn't play nicely (clicking full screen plays the video, but not in fullscreen).

Furthermore sometimes windows pops up on my second screen (which is an LCD TV usually turned off) which is inconvenient.

Disabling Xinerama / Twinview solves these problems, but it would be nice to move windows back and forth between the two screens.

Answer (score 1):

I have a dual monitor setup too and I'm using the open source nouveau driver. I haven't seen any performance issues when playing flash and it works like Twinview. If you don't want windows to open on your secondary monitor you can disable it temporarily via System->Preferences->Monitors.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to use the nouveau driver too, but it doesn't controls my video card's fan and it's extremely loud without the proprietary driver. However Twinview and Xinerama are acting up like this way.

Furthermore disabling / re-enabling monitors are rather inconvenient. *We* use *nix, but that doesn't mean we should give up on comfort. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways one can get multiple monitors working.  Both ATI and nVidia have their solutions (Xinerama/TwinView) as well as X having it's own solution.

If you use Xinerama/TwinView, you run into certain limitations, such as no composite, no 3D acceleration, etc.  When you use separate X screens, you have less of these issues while losing some of the functionality provided (like being able to drag between monitors).

When using separate X screens, you have multiple **DISPLAY** s.  You can set which display to run an application on by defining it in your .*bashrc* or prefixing the command with **DISPLAY=:0.0** or **DISPLAY=:0.1**.

Back to your original problem: Have you tried both TwinView and Xinerama by themselves, or both together?